# Is there a way to compute leave one out estimates for GLM in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation, glm

I'm trying to get the leave-one-out coefficient estimates for `glm` models in R. The context is not on cross validation, though.

Here's my simple loop version implementation:

```
data("mtcars")
res <- matrix(nrow = nrow(mtcars), ncol = 3L)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(mtcars))) {
  loo.data <- mtcars[-i, ]
  model <- glm(vs ~ mpg + disp, family = binomial, data = loo.data)
  res[i, ] <- model$coefficients
}
```

After the loop, I get a matrix of coefficients where each row consists of leave-one-out estimates. The number of rows in `res` is the same as the total number of observations. The `res` does not have to be a matrix format.

Is there a cleaner and perhaps faster way to get the same result? It will be used in other C++ code. I found `cv.glm` in boot package but it does not seem to be applicable in my case. Is using Rcpp `Function` class could be an option? Writing the Fisher scoring algorithm in C++ seems just waste of time and effort. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that there is a closed formula for GLM's that allows recomputation of coefficients when the training data changes. `boot::cv.glm` computes the leave-one-out Brier score, and although you can provide a different cost function, you cannot return the coefficients instead. If you look at the source code of `cv.glm`, you will notice that this function does exactly the same as your code.

Comment: @cdalitz Thanks for pointing out. I will check the source code.